# How to use named url in the next_page parameter to redirect after log out?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have the following code in urls.py file of one of my apps.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', SignUpView.as_view(), name="signup"),
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}, name="logout"),
]
```

Instead of using '/' as 'next_page' parameter value, I want to use named parameter like 'home' or 'index'. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass in the reverse name for the view as the value for the `next_page` parameter, as [`django.contrib.auth.views.logout` uses](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L106) [`django.shortcuts.resolve_url`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/shortcuts.py#L175), which its docs describe as

> Return a URL appropriate for the arguments passed.
>   The arguments could be:
>
> - A model: the model's `get_absolute_url()` function will be called.
> - A view name, possibly with arguments: `urlresolvers.reverse()` will
>     be used to reverse-resolve the name.
> - A URL, which will be returned as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reverse_lazy() for all cases where you need to get the actual url from a url name.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', SignUpView.as_view(), name="signup"),
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': reverse_lazy('home')}, name="logout"),
]
```